# Getting below error while doing ng serve after upgrading from angular 12 to angular 13

Tags: angular

./projects/dx-gui/src/lib/dx-wizard/dx-wizard.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
BrowserslistError: Unknown version 103 of android
at Function.select (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:1096:17)
at /Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:314:29
at Array.reduce ()
at resolve (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:304:34)
at browserslist (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:406:21)
at Browsers.parse (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:54:12)
at new Browsers (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:42:26)
at loadPrefixes (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:106:20)
at Object.prepare (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:120:22)
at /Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:149:39
at Array.map ()
at new LazyResult (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:147:43)
at Processor.process (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:28:14)
at Object.loader (/Users/kapilmittal/workspace/dx-gui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:97:30)

I tried updating the angular packages to angular 13.

Comment: How did you do the update? Did you follow https://update.angular.io/? Did you just update the versions in the package.json? etc etc

Comment: It got fixed after removing the yarn lock file and regenerating the node_modules.